# Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type LoginViewModel is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type LoginViewModel is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
//THIS IS THE ERROR I GOT

[screenshot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxzZ7.png)

[one more screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2HD6.png)

i do not understand what it means by this error. Please explain

HERE IS THE GIT REPO LINK:https://github.com/soam1/Tut-app-Flutter.git

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more, it is hard to know what you need help with.

However, check out [this repo](https://github.com/mattrltrent/clean_architecture_weather_app) to see how simple dependency injection with [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) should work.

Specifically, check out the [dependency injection](https://github.com/mattrltrent/clean_architecture_weather_app/blob/main/lib/dependency_injection.dart) file and how I set it up from [main](https://github.com/mattrltrent/clean_architecture_weather_app/blob/main/lib/main.dart).

I think you're not properly doing what is shown in the dependency injection file of this repo.

Comment: sir I have less idea of all that. I have added (edited) the repo link. Can you please have a look at that Sir.